# How to use a proxy api in R

Tags: r, api, proxy

I'm using a proxy service IP in R which I have configured perfectly by the following: 
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-or-HTTPS-Proxy

This service, which im not sure if I can mention here, also offers a proxy API.
 e.g. https://xxxx.com/proxy-api/7976ed1223443d907283443dffc961ff2c9bb219_993353-2033906

I'm using the proxy service for a **read_html** script from **library(rvest)**.

Would it be possible, if more efficient, to use proxy API, rather than modifying the **Renviron.site** file?

Comment: You may export proxy environment variables globally.

Answer (score 0):

solved it as follows:

```
library(jsonlite)

json_file <- "https://xxxx.com/proxy-api/7976ed1223443d907283443dffc961ff2c9bb219_993353-2033906"
json_data <- fromJSON(json_file, flatten=TRUE)
x<-sample(1:5, 1)
Sys.setenv(http_proxy = json_data[x])
Sys.setenv(https_proxy = json_data[x])
```